# Assign variable to minimum date based on a within group difference

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I would like to create a variable date that is equal to the most recent date for which a storm(name) has become a hurricane or existed(if tropical storm).

Here is an example data frame:

```
hurricane<- data.frame("year"=c(2011,2012,2013,2011,2012,2013), 

"category"=c("TS","H","H","TS","TS","TS"), 

"name"=c("alex","alex","alex","bob","bob","bob"))
```

I would like a date variable that is equal to the most recent date the hurricane was classified as a hurricane or the most recent date the storm shows up if it never became a hurricane. I.e for alex's date will be 2012 for each observation and bob's will be 2011.

So far I have been trying countless iterations of group_by %>% mutate and ifelse statements but have not gotten very far.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   library(tidyverse)
   hurricane%>%
            group_by(name)%>%
            mutate(a =  if_else(any(category=='H'),year[category=='H'][1],min(year)))
    # A tibble: 6 x 4
    # Groups:   name [2]
       year category name      a
      <dbl> <fct>    <fct> <dbl>
    1  2011 TS       alex   2012
    2  2012 H        alex   2012
    3  2013 H        alex   2012
    4  2011 TS       bob    2011
    5  2012 TS       bob    2011
    6  2013 TS       bob    2011
```